# How to query the repository descriptor table in JackRabbit 2?

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

I'm using JackRabbit 2.18.0 and would like to figure out whether I can use one or more of the different query features:

> 6.1 Optional Joins
>   Support for joins is optional beyond support for query itself. The extent of join support can be determined by querying the repository descriptor table with the key
>
> Repository.QUERY_JOINS.
>
> The value returned will be one of
>
> • QUERY_JOINS_NONE: Joins are not supported and therefore queries are
>   limited to a single selector.
>   • QUERY_JOINS_INNER: Inner joins are supported.
>   • QUERY_JOINS_INNER_OUTER: Inner and outer joins are supported.

(from JCR 2.0 Specification, p. 100)

The requirement to query this table in order to find out about support for certain features is mentioned a dozen times in the specification, but I find no information about how to do that (I wouldn't expect it in the specification because it's an implementation details, however I still just need the information).

Answer (score 0):

It's a set of methods on the `Repository` instance. See around https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Repository.html#getDescriptorValue(java.lang.String).